# Why fixed-gear for track racing?

Tags: fixed-gear, track-racing

I have what seems like a really simple question, and yet I didn't manage to find the answer.

Why do track races require fixed-gear bicycles, as opposed to single-speed freewheeled bicycles? Is it purely for traditional/historical reasons, or is there any good reason for that requirement?

Comment: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2002/why-don-t-fixed-gear-bikes-have-brakes

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A lot of mystique grows up around the regulation of many sports. The key (as [Neo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo_%28The_Matrix%29) says) is to get to the source ...

**UCI regulations** say

> **Section 2: bicycles**
>
> **Preamble**
>
> Bicycles  shall  comply  with  the  spirit  and  principle  of  cycling  as  a  sport.  The  spirit 
>   presupposes  that cyclists  will  compete  in  competitions  on  an  equal  footing.  The  principle asserts the primacy of man over machine.
>
> ...
>
> **1.3.025**
>
> Freewheels, multiple gears and brakes are not permitted for use on the track during competition or training.

See [UCI CYCLING REGULATIONS GENERAL ORGANISATION OF CYCLING AS A SPORT PART 1 GENERAL ORGANISATION OF CYCLING AS A SPORT](http://www.uci.ch/mm/Document/News/Rulesandregulation/16/26/49/1-GEN-20141101-E_English.pdf) (pdf).

The main reason behind this rule is safety. Crashes are, and always have been, common in track racing. Anything that can drop onto the track is forbidden. Freewheels and gears can drop oil, or otherwise fail, causing a crash. Gears (currently) always have some loopy control cable that could entangle another competitor.

Brakes are unnecessary because of the closed environment and the use of fixed wheels. Levers and cables can fail, and brake blocks can come out. In any case they would add weight to the bike, which would cost time in sprints.

So in general it's all about minimising equipment failure possibilities, and maximising the competitor vs competitor aspect.

Comment: As an aside, I am always amazed when professional athletes don't know the rules of their sport, as we see from time to time, and as exemplified in the [Giro](http://www.bicycling.com/racing/pro-cycling/generosity-ruins-richie-porte-s-giro-d-italia-hopes). It just doesn't seem ... *professional*.

Comment: Thanks for that detailed answer, I'm quite satisfied with it.